# Access data from a join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to select a user's groups where the join table is marked with `favorit: true`.

I have `User` which has `Groups` through a join table named `UsersGroup`. The `UsersGroup` model have the variables `group_id` and `user_id`, but also a variable `favorit`.

I would like to call the favorit groups of my users. But I don't know how to write it.

I've tried something like this :

```
current_user.groups.joins(:users_group).where(:users_group => { :favorit => true })
```

&

```
current_user.groups.where(users_group.favorit == true)
```

Do you have a solution for this kind of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`current_user.user_groups.where(favorit: true)`

If you want to access the groups from this, you can get the `group` from the `user_groups` found above. I.E.

```
favorits = current_user.user_groups.where(favorit: true).includes(:group)
favorits.map(&:group)
```

Notice the `includes` in there to eager load the groups and avoid any N + 1 issues.

Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot @SRack for your answer. It's exactly what i'm looking for !!